# Having image stretch and fill column

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a promo section I'm trying to add to my site. The promo section has 3 images. First one on the left column, the next two images are vertically aligned on the second column. The 2 images on the second column are perfect, the image on the left is not adjusting to the correct size, it should stretch and fill the entire column.

**The Code (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZGzOw):**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-8 columns">
    <p>
      <img src="http://www.bandwagonbible.com/Stories/Lifestyle/AprilFoolsPrank/Main.jpg">
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-4 columns">
    <p>
      <img src="http://www.bandwagonbible.com/Stories/LifeHacks/GetRich/Image4.jpg" alt="advertisement for deep fried Twinkies" class="nostyle">
    </p>
    <p>
      <img src="http://www.bandwagonbible.com/Stories/Fitness/GettingSixPackAbs/Image2.jpg" alt="article promo image" class="nostyle">
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the image style to have max height/max width 100%, width/height auto.

Comment: stretch vertically? just set `height:100%;width:auto;`. It will match the height and keep the horizontal aspect ratio

Comment: @ShamSUP Is there a way to get it to be more responsive/ As I shrink the window, the aspect ratio goes weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to preserve the aspect ratio, then `flex-box` is the solution.

Give

```
.row {
  display: flex;
}
.medium-8{
  flex: 1.50; // adjust this for better aspect ratio
}
.medium-4{
  flex: 0.55; // adjust this for better aspect ratio
}
```

remove the `p` tag above the image for better results.

See this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/JXrKWR)**

Comment: Hi @Jinu, You solution works perfectly for full screens. But it's no longer responsive. As I shrink the screen, the images shrink, but it should stack on top of eachother as it shrinks and adjust to the screen if it can no longer display "normally"

Comment: @Master : I will check this and get back to you :)